# Не хотят появляться кнопки в боте для телеграма, в чем может быть причина?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Не хотят появляться кнопки, в чём может быть причина?

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN') 
@bot.message_handler(commands =['start'])
def start(message):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
        ButtonA = types.KeyboardButton('привет')
        buttonB = types.KeyboardButton('помощь')
    
        markup.row(buttonA, buttonB)
    
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'работает', reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Он и с отсупами, и без не работает. Кнопки не хотят появляться

Comment: `Он и с отсупами, и без не работает` — отступы - это часть синтаксиса. они должны быть в тех местах, где полагается согласно синтаксису языка и задуманной логике программы.

Comment: он и с правильными отступами не работает

Answer (score 0):

```
markup.row(buttonA, buttonB)
```

замените на

```
markup.add(buttonA, buttonB)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN') 

@bot.message_handler(commands =['start'])
def start(message):
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)#здесь вы можете поиграть из цифрами
    buttonA = types.KeyboardButton(text = 'привет')
    buttonB = types.KeyboardButton(text = 'помощь')
    markup_inline.add(buttonA, buttonB)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'работает', reply_markup=markup)
```

еще я у вас нашел ошибку

```
    ButtonA = types.KeyboardButton('привет')
    buttonB = types.KeyboardButton('помощь')
    markup.row(buttonA, buttonB)
```

у вас не правильно написанные переменные в markup.row(buttonA, buttonB)